# OmniFaces equivalent of Seam <s:validateForm> to validate multiple fields

Tags: validation, jsf, omnifaces

in seam faces is option of a validation of a whole form. 
I can import:

```
xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/seam/faces"
```

and use:

```
<s:validateForm validatorId="oneOrMorePrimaryIndicesValidator"/>
```

Now we have to use omnifaces instead of seamfaces.

Is there any equivalent in omnifaces that do similar job?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the concrete functional requirement which isn't entirely clear from the question.

If you want to validate if one or more fields are filled out, use existing [`<o:validateOneOrMore>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore):

```
<o:validateOneOrMore components="foo bar baz" />
<h:inputText id="foo" />
<h:inputText id="bar" />
<h:inputText id="baz" />
```

Or, if you want to implement a custom validator for multiple fields, use [`<o:validateMultiple>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple):

```
<o:validateMultiple components="foo bar baz" validator="#{oneOrMorePrimaryIndicesValidator}" />
<h:inputText id="foo" />
<h:inputText id="bar" />
<h:inputText id="baz" />
```

Whereby `#{oneOrMorePrimaryIndicesValidator}` refers a managed bean (can be either JSF or CDI) which implements [`MultiFieldValidator`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/validator/MultiFieldValidator.html):

```
@Named
@RequestScoped // Can also be @ApplicationScoped, depending on if validator should hold state.
public class OneOrMorePrimaryIndicesValidator implements MultiFieldValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean validateValues(FacesContext context, List<UIInput> components, List<Object> values) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

It should return `false` if values are invalid, otherwise `true`.

Either way, general usage instructions on e.g. `components`, `message`, `invalidateAll` and `showMessageFor` attributes can be found in [`ValidateMultipleFields`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.0/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateMultipleFields.html) javadoc.

---

A completely different alternative is to use [`<o:validateBean>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean) with JSR303 bean validation groups to validate an entity at class level with a JSR303 `ConstraintValidator<SomeGroupAnnotation, Bean>`. Such a validator is not only useable in JSF (the web tier), but also in e.g. JPA (the data tier). E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.foo}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.bar}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.baz}" />
<o:validateBean value="#{bean.entity}" validationGroups="com.example.SomeGroup" />
```

A more concrete example is hard to give without having concrete code of current model and validator at hands.